# Reading dput() gists from github into R

Tags: ruby, r, reproducible-research

I am trying to read a gist containing a `dput` from Github:

```
library(RCurl)
data <- getURL("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aronlindberg/848b8efef154d0e7fdb4/raw/5bf4bb864cc4c1db0f66da1be85515b4fa19bf6b/pull_lists")
pull_lists <- dget(textConnection(data))
```

This generates:

```
Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""@@ -1,7 +1,9 @@
 module ActionDispatch
   module Http
     module URL
-      # Returns the complete \U"
```

Which I think is a `Ruby` error message rather than an R error. Now consider this:

```
data <- getURL("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aronlindberg/b6b934b39e3c3378c3b2/raw/9b1efe9340c5b1c8acfdc90741260d1d554b2af0/data")
 pull_lists2 <- dget(textConnection(data))
```

This seems to work fine. The former gist is rather large, 1.7mb. Could this be why I can't read it from Github. If not, why?

Comment: Have you looked at the `source_gist()` function in the `devtools` package? And just to be clear, you get this error with just the `getURL` call? or do you get data in your "data" variable?

Comment: @MrFlick: I tried `source_gist("https://gist.github.com/aronlindberg/b6b934b39e3c3378c3b2")` which should load the second gist which works with my approach. However, with `source_gist()` this does not seem to work: `Error: No R files found in gist`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gist that you created does not have a `.R` file in it, since `pull_lists` does not have an extension. I forked [your gist](https://gist.github.com/aronlindberg/848b8efef154d0e7fdb4/) to [this one](https://gist.github.com/lmullen/a7b157cec3b9259fc5d1) and added the extension. Now it is possible to source the gist and save it to a value.

```
library("devtools")
pull_lists <- source_gist("a7b157cec3b9259fc5d1")
```